# What was Vittoria Conti's date of birth and date of death?

Tags: 18th-century, mathematics, famous-people

What is the exact date of birth and exact date of death of Vittoria Conti?

She was the first wife of [Joseph-Louis Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph-Louis_Lagrange), a famous Italian-French mathematician.

So far I have these vague dates:
Vittoria was born in "about" 1745 in Sardegna, Regno di Sardegna. She and Lagrange got married in September 1767.  She died in 1783.

Known years come from Wikipedia, and [WikiData](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q22348223), place of birth is from here: https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Conti-366 (which apparently gives an incorrect year for her death)

Comment: Since you're probably interested in this as well, despite being out of scope for the Q. 10.1007/s40329-014-0046-0 adds an additional approaching tidbit: they "married in _September_ 1767"

Comment: @SteveBird Precise observation, but in this case WikiTree gives in error their marriage date as her death date.

Comment: From WikiTree I have the place of birth only. The dates I have now are from Wikipedia.